# How to save a message from a telegram chat and send other messages with your own account?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

I want to build a code that save a certain telegram message, **from a user**, as an input (ex: "David: *Hello how are you doing?*") and be able to send a certain message back, with **my own telegram account** (ex: "Me: *I'm fine! How are you?*")

Is there a way I can do this in python **without using a telegram bot**? Because I dont think bots can actually connect to your own telegram account and send messages

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way to achieve this kind of results is by creating **your own customized Telegram app**, take a look at the API docs at https://core.telegram.org/api